# Assembly language Average of arr

Tags: assembly, x86-64, calling-convention, att

I am starting learn assebly(86-64,AT&T syntax)and I have problems with finding avearge of array(aver should be in float), could you give some example how can I find it .Here part of my code

```
    movq counter,%rcx   #counter stored how many elements in arr I have                                                           
    cvtsi2sd %rcx,%xmm1 
    cvtsi2sd %rbx,%xmm0  #in rbx sum of my arr
    divsd %xmm1,%xmm0
    pushq %rbp
    movq $format2,%rdi
    movq %xmm0, %rsi
    call printf
```

Comment: You already found the average.  I think you just forgot to `mov $1, %eax` to tell printf that you're passing an FP arg in `%xmm0`.  (remove `movq %xmm0, %rsi`, printf doesn't want FP args in integer registers).  What format string did you use?

Comment: I have  used      format2: .asciz "\nAver is : %d\n "

Comment: Use `%f`.  You're printing (as a decimal integer) the low 32 bits of the bit pattern that represents your [`double` (aka IEEE binary64)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format).  BTW, you can't use `printf` with a `float`, only `double`, but you are already using `...sd` instructions so that's what you have.

Comment: Thank you very much, I'm gonna follow your advices=)

Comment: Hi, is the question still pending ? )